# Access rights on Snap Server

Tags: permissions

We have a Snap server (Snap Appliance 1100) that we have outgrown. The server is running SnapOS 4.0.855.

We're looking for a way to enumerate permissions for all files and folders on the server. The output should be something that is human readable. A CSV or text file would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have a much easier time by copying files to your new server with the permissions rather than dumping the permissions and trying to reapply them.

Assuming SMB, if you use robocopy with /DATSOU, that copies data, attributes, timestamps, security (permissions, NTFS ACLs), owner, and auditing. Run it with verbose logging, output to a file so you can spot-check.

If you really need what you're asking for, run xcacls.exe against every directory and file on the SnapServer and keep that list too.

Comment: We'd still want to have a list of the permissions so that we could double check that they had copied properly.

Comment: That's fairly silly, IMO. Keep the verbose log from robocopy which will show any errors, and spot-check a sample of files if you're really paranoid.

Comment: That said, run xcacls.exe against every directory and file on the SnapServer.

Comment: Only errors from xcacls. Likely b/c the server is not a Windows/NTFS server.

**************************************************************************
Directory: G:\

No Permissions set

No Auditing set
Error 424:  occurred setting objOwner = objSecDescriptor.Owner. (Msg#404)
Error description: Object required
**************************************************************************

Comment: Did you run it against an actual named file, see if you get different results?